# Vectorize this, filter string arrays by a string? GPU pipeline?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, search, vectorization

I did search SO but didn't find for using something like MPICH or vectorization.  In fortran, I'd use MPICH to break up the code to paralyze.

This is to run on an iPad with Metal available.

I have a 1-D string array with many hundred of thousands of elements, many are duplicates.  I want to find the duplicates' indices.

So far I'm using the simple loop but it's slow so am looking a way to vectorize this or divide and conquer if possible? or maybe there is a way to use the pipelines in Metal?

```
  class func filterDatabyString(dataString:[String],filterString:String) -> [Int]
  {
    var arrayIndex:[Int] = []
    var i:Int = 0

    for (i = 0; i < dataString.count; i++) {
      if dataString[i] == filterString
      {
        arrayIndex.append(i)
      }
    }

    return (arrayIndex)
  }
```

Comment: So why do you want to find the indices of the duplicates? Also, aren't all the duplicates the same? So why do you need to throw them all into an array?

Comment: Put them in a hash. If it exists its a duplicate.

Comment: Did you vote down my question?  No, there are other arrays that are have dependencies so I need the indices.

Comment: Putting in a hash seems like it will add much more overhead.  Why convert to/from hash when I already have arrays?  Also I need indices, hash is unordered.

Comment: No I did not down vote you. I mean the string. All the strings are the same as filterString so why save them in an array. Also it would be more efficient to just do `arrayFiltered.append(filterString)` instead of grabbing it again from dataString.

Comment: Generally you use Hash to get O(1) search. Looking at your current code you should be getting O(n^2) instead of O(n) for overall code, no amount of parallelization will help to overcome that.

Comment: Yes, I realize it's slow O(n^2) that's why I'm asking the question.  Why isn't is possible to pipeline on the GPU?  Where are the hooks for GPU?

Comment: The strings are not all the same, the total elements in the dataString array is around ~800k elements, there are about ~5k duplicate elements.  So each duplicate will have ~160 indices, I need it's indices to process other arrays.

Comment: To be clear, you need to support duplicates, and you want to find all the indices of the filterString, correct? I don't see the point of `arrayFiltered`. All elements in it will be the same string as `filterString`. Either that or it'll be empty.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean, you are correct, I've edited the code.  The filtered array wasn't needed.

Comment: @Levenkov Of course there is, in fortran it's called MPICH or MPI or using the CUDA GPU library to unroll the loops, divide and conquer.

Comment: @GAlexander I'm not sure why you want to parallelize O(n^2) version instead of using hash to detect if item is duplicate and split your list in get O(n) time... Indeed it is interesting exercise...

Comment: @Levenkov Hash is one way.  But if something is already O(1), how are you going to make this more efficient?  If something is O(n^2), there is room to optimize.  I'm evaluating the Concurrent method from Ben Kane and the GPU/OpenCL method.  If you had a massive matrix, M x N x S x T and needed to optimize and sort based on 1 variable in N.  Now make this run on an iPad.  As I don't see anything like google's Big Table search implemented, I use what it is available.

Comment: Has Apple been reading my posts `https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/MetalPartialSumsCompute/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015013-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your `dataString` array an `NSArray` and enumerate concurrently. How about something like this?

```
func filterDataByString(dataString:[String], filterString:String) -> [Int]
{
    var arrayIndex = [Int]()
    let data = dataString as NSArray
    data.enumerateObjectsWithOptions(.Concurrent) { (string: AnyObject!, index: Int, stop:UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void in
        if(string as! String == filterString)
        {
            arrayIndex.append(index)
        }
    };

    return arrayIndex
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will benchmark this as well.  Do you know of any way to utilize the GPU to pipeline this?

Comment: I don't know how offhand, no. Let me know the benchmark results please.

Comment: You may want to look into [Using GCD with OpenCL](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/OpenCL_MacProgGuide/UsingGCDwOpenCL/UsingGCDwOpenCL.html). Don't think that it's available on iOS though. At least not publicly.

Comment: [Here's an article](http://ciechanowski.me/blog/2014/01/05/exploring_gpgpu_on_ios/) about using OpenGL for this and a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/Ciechan/Exploring-GPGPU-on-iOS) to go with it.

Comment: Cool, thanks.  I'll write some of the OpenCL/Metal code and generate a benchmark too...  well as long as the question doesn't get voted to oblivion.  If it does, I'll PM you the timings.

Comment: After averaging 20 runs, using  `enumerateObjectsWithOptions(.Concurrent)`   is about 1.5x faster than simple looping.

Answer (score 1):

```
filter(enumerate(dataString)) { $0.1 == filterString }.map { $0.0 }
```

If you only need the index, then this example would be suffice. I'm not sure if this would be faster though. Kinda curious.

Comment: Since you only need the index, I changed my answer. I wonder how fast `map` is compared to a `for-loop` or the example of Ben Kane.

Comment: Ok, give me a little time, I'm not sure of how much map has overhead.  I use map in perl but perl is optimized for these kind of operations.  Doesn't this map return bool?

Comment: I've been testing it a bit. Ben's example is by far the fastest. Wops, looks like I copy pasted the wrong code!

Comment: How many orders of magnitude faster did  you get with Ben's code than with the map?  I'm going to have a go at that OpenCL code now.

Comment: Well, with filter/map it just looks better. There's no way it can beat Ben's code, which is concurrently. In my test with 10.000 objects, Ben's code finished in 3 seconds and 2,51 seconds and with filter/map it took 7,72 seconds.

Comment: Is this map thread safe?  Why can't your code be wrapped inside .Concurrent?

Comment: Here is some code that claims to be an asynchronous map.  `http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/62006/asynchronous-array-map`